# Double checked locking not a concern because of implicit memory barrier?

Tags: java, correctness

I am reviewing a piece of code and noticed a double checked locking implementation for setting a session lock:

```
Lock lock = getLock(mySession);
if (lock == null) {
    synchronized (myService.class) {
        lock = getLock(mySession);
        if (lock == null) {
            lock = new ReentrantLock();
            setLock(mySession, lock);
        }
    }
}
```

There was a comment along with this code snippet that said the developer assumed there was a memory barrier for the attribute: the CPU will flush its caches and read the value from main memory directly.

Is this a good assumption, or would the best practice still be to define 'lock' as volatile to guarantee it?

Comment: whatever member variable actually holds the lock passed to `setLock` must be volatile. Otherwise, `getLock` may return a non-null lock, but the changes made by the `ReentrantLock` constructor may not have propagated to the thread that calls `getLock`

Comment: Please do not think in terms of "flushing" caches - think in terms of change visibility. If two changes are made on thread A in some order, And the last change is seen by thread B, it's not guaranteed that the first change will be seen by B as well, unless there is some sort of barrier: synchronized section enter/exit, volatile assignment/read and so on.

Comment: Q: Why use lazy eval to create the lock objects?  Have you _proved_ that it improves the program in any way?  It's possible that the cost of simply entering and leaving the `synchronized` block is higher than the cost of constructing a new `ReentrantLock` that never gets used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your code is block or method scoped:

```
public void mymethod() {
//...
Lock lock = getLock(mySession);
if (lock == null) {
    synchronized (myService.class) {
        lock = getLock(mySession);
        if (lock == null) {
            lock = new ReentrantLock();
            setLock(mySession, lock);
        }
    }
}
//...
}
```

The double checking issue does not apply to it at all, as `lock` is a local variable (allocated on the thread's stack), so each Thread sees it's own copy of it, and there is no concurrent access to it (which is an essential precondition for the double checking issues).

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean for the method-scoped `lock` variable. But what about the lock that is a member of the session (returned by `getLock`)? If one thread runs `setLock`, couldn't a new thread come and still run `setLock`, if the new thread doesn't see the complete instantiation? (If my understanding of the comment @Arkadiy made above is correct).

Comment: The thread running `setLock` does so inside the synchronized block, so the other thread won't be able to enter it, until the first one returns from the `setLock`. Also the `lock` is constructed before it is passed to the `setLock`, so it is fully constructed by that point.

Comment: Yes, I see now. 
Thanks for a great answer!

Comment: @zeppelin, the thing is that by the time `setLock` has finished writing, some other thread using `getLock` outside the synchronized block may get a non-null object which initialization was not entirely made visible outside the originating thread.  In this specific case, you're lucky `ReentrantLock` only has final and volatile fields, but for any object with regular fields, you have a data race.